# write() function returning ULLONG_MAX?

Tags: network-programming

I'm building upon JPerf (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jperf/) which is the GUI that runs over the C program, IPerf (https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/). IPerf basically measures the bandwidth of a network link by the client issuing the write() command to the server, and executing some logic to measure the bandwidth.

In a nutshell, the issue that I'm experiencing is as follows: if I unplug the network cable between the client and the server, wait around 10 sec, and then plug it back in, the write() function returns the value of ULLONG_MAX, and it continues to do that no matter how long I wait.

Has anyone ever experienced this while using write() to write over a network connection? My ultimate goal is to have the function recover the connection and continue to transfer data even after unplug and replug.

Thanks in advance for any input you might have!

EDIT: After plugging the network cable back in, the errno value is "Connection reset by peer" then it switches to "Broken pipe"

Does anyone know how I can recover the connection?